How can i connect to s3 bucket from power BI. I need to load images from s3 bucket to the paginated report
I am new to power bi and i need to load images from s3 bucket to my paginated report. I have to load images based on id. What's the best way to connect to s3 and get files based on id.
I am tried searching it. but unable to get any answers.

Can connect depends on whether Is it okay to make this images public?

@AmilaMGunawardana, no i can't expose to public.
